# Swing paintComponent() doesn't seem to reset on translucent JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, drag, transparent, paintcomponent

I am currently working on an overlay and testing every function out first.

The overlay should be completely translucent and only the elements, i.e. Components or String, should be displayed.
Also, I would like to add a feature that makes dragging Panels possible.

My problem now is: I have drawn the rectangle onto the transparent background. Any time I drag it to another position, the rendering fails and the old projection does not get cleared.
Also, the whole frame flashes when I start to drag. I think I might need to repaint it in a separate thread while the mouse button is held down, right?

I have tried many things until now, but none of them seemed to work to resolve the rendering error.

Here is my code. Thanks for the help in advance.

Frame.java

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public Frame() {
    super();

    setLayout(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setSize(600, 600);
    Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setLocation(screensize.width / 2 - getWidth() / 2, screensize.height / 2 - getHeight() / 2);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 0));
    DragPanel dp = new DragPanel();
    dp.setSize(100, 100);
    dp.setLocation(10, 10);
    JButton bt = new JButton("TEST");
    bt.setSize(100, 30);
    bt.setLocation(getWidth() - 20 - bt.getWidth(), getHeight() - 20 - bt.getHeight());
    bt.addActionListener(this);
    c.add(dp);
    c.add(bt);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    this.repaint();
}

}
```

DragPanel.java

```
public class DragPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

private int screenX = 0;
private int screenY = 0;
private int compX = 0;
private int compY = 0;

public DragPanel() {
    setOpaque(false);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    screenX = e.getXOnScreen();
    screenY = e.getYOnScreen();
    compX = getX();
    compY = getY();
    Starter.f.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    int dX = e.getXOnScreen() - screenX;
    int dY = e.getYOnScreen() - screenY;
    setLocation(compX + dX, compY + dY);
    Starter.f.repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(3, 3, getWidth() - 6, getHeight() - 6);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably containers do not like moving UI parts so you have to "render" it yourself. You have to overwrite the paint method and clear the background and do what the container does, you issue a paint request to every component. For me this worked without problems.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    for(Component c: getContentPane().getComponents()) {
        c.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the JFrame to paint, when you're setting a transparent background color? Of course it doesnt "reset". From your description I still fail to see for what you would need *any transparency* at all.

If your goal is to make the entire JFrame transparent with respect to the desktop, your approach is *meaningless*. You need to explicitly make the frame transparent, which is easily found using google: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick response. The reason for the need of a transparent JFrame is because I would like to create an overlay over the map of a game.
I tried to use the Per-Pixel Translucency from the documentation and managed to create a panel with it as the content pane.
That didn't seem to help though: Now, all of a sudden, both the button and the DragPanel are resized and repositioned without me doing anything. Also, when I try to drag the panel away, it still does not render properly ontop of the transparent panel and the transparent JFrame.

Comment: Help appreciated.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/kPx1bdqL

EDIT: FYI Translucency is supported by my system
http://pastebin.com/Wa00fVA1
http://pastebin.com/YNJrthmw

Comment: If you're having layout problems, you should look into that. Its most likely not related to transparency at all, you probably just didn't notice it before with rendering problems. Most likely the default LayoutManager doesn't like the way you have implemented your drag function. Use LayoutManager's properly, or not at all: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#set

Comment: I did not use any LayoutManager at all, I set it to null. Everything worked properly until I implemented the new Paint

Comment: The code you pasted does not set a LayoutManager at all. Nobody on SO  is a psychic and can tell you whats wrong with code you don't show. Maybe you should take a break and then work the problem out systematically, asking questions with a narrowly scoped topic. Just attributing "after I changed X and unrelated Y broke" is frustrating for both me (because I know its unlikely) and you (because you make no progress).

Comment: Line 6 of Frame.java in my initial post clearly says "setLayout(null);". Anyways, thanks for your time